# How to get child records into a ruby hash in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a reservation system in Ruby on Rails and want to allow the user to be able to choose a bed in the building of their choice. I have created a table to hold the building records and setup a relationship to another table that holds the available beds. My front end uses React with the react_on_rails gem to list out the buildings in panels. But I am unable to include the child records (list of beds) in the json sent into my React component. Please see code example below. I know it has to be something small that I am missing. Thanks for the help.

```
@event_show_props = {
     buildings: @event.Buildings
                      .eager_load(:Room_Beds)
                      .index_by(&:id),
}

respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json {render json: @event_show_props}
end
```

Comment: You could try using `as_json`, `@event.Buildings.eager_load(:Room_Beds).as_json(include: :room_beds)` (or `Room_Beds`, it depends on how the relation is set)

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment above on the question I added a .as_json method to the string and it worked. The list of room_beds where added as an array under their own key. See full code below. Not sure who to give credit too, but thanks! I thought it would be a simple simple solution.

```
buildings: @event.Buildings
                 .eager_load(:Room_Beds)
                 .index_by(&:id)
                 .as_json(include: :Room_Beds),
```